# Drupal commerce: there is a way to apply discount to products with some taxonomies elements?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

I would like to know if there is a way to apply discount to products with some taxonomies values, something similar to "bulk views operations" Or another way where a non developer or not a site-builder it's able to create new discounts.

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue here is that in your taxonomy term comparisons, Rules is going to be looking for taxonomy term IDs. In core Rules, there is no way to show a select list or something similar in the Rules UI for selecting a taxonomy term. There may be a contributed module that adds this functionality; I didn't look.

If you know a term ID, you can use a different condition based on whether the term reference field is single or multi value:

- Single value: Data comparison
- Multi value: List contains item

Since you're going for usefulness to non-developers / site builders, I'll assume you need something better than that. It appears you might be using Commerce Discount, but I don't know if that's why you've added the tag or not. It offers a simplified interface for building product pricing rules and depends on the http://drupal.org/project/inline_conditions module, which includes a simplified taxonomy term check for product entities.

Comment: Hello Ryan, the problem is that the Customers is not a sitebuilder. And I'm looking for a GUI that let him to move a lot of product to some kind of offers. As it's my first commerce, I think I have to go deep into the commerce API to see if I can Build some kind of Bulk Operations to make this.
Thanks.